# Put and get data from table containing BLOB,CLOB raw by raw in oracle

Tags: c++, database, oracle, blob, clob

I have this table and I want to put data using C++ raw by raw in oracle.

```
CREATE TABLE blob_fun (
  username VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  iblob    BLOB   ,
  iclob    CLOB   ,
  codeID NUMBER(5)
);
```

how to put data to this like

```
insert into blob_fun values('BOB',HOW?,HOW?,12563);
```

and how to get data from this raw by raw

Comment: Have you tried something? [how to insert raw data into oracle blob column using c++](https://www.google.com.np/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=how%20to%20insert%20raw%20data%20into%20oracle%20blob%20column%20using%20c%2B%2B&oq=how%20to%20insert%20raw%20data%20into%20oracle%20blob%20column%20using%20c%2B%2B&aqs=chrome..69i57.21519j0j7)

Comment: yes but there isn't a method  to get the a single row to row datatype including all blob and other data type.there's only select only blob type column per one time